# Jquery .on click event - removing the bound element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following code:

```
$("#content h1").on("click", function(){
        var f = $(this);
        var clicked_id = f.data("id");


        var children = _.filter(data, function(key){
            var id = key.id.split("-")
            id.pop()
            id = id.join("-")
            return clicked_id == id;
        });

        if (children.length != 0) {
            $("#content").html("");
            _.each(children, function(obj){
                $("#content").append("<h1 data-id='"+ obj.id +"'>"+ obj.txt +"</h1>")
            });
        }
    });
```

So basicly Im binding a .on "click" event to h1. On the click I clean the element containing the H1 then I add a new H1 element. Now the click does not register anymore. How should I actually be doing this so I can keep clicking?

Answer (score 1):

Use `on` like so (event delegation):

```
$("#content").on("click", "h1", function() {
```

Now, each time you click `#content`, it'll check for an `h1` and run the event. Your previous code only bound the handler to the `h1` at runtime.

Comment: Ah yes, thanks, stupid me, I have not been using Jquery for some time, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could bind this way?

```
$(document).on("click", "#content h1", function(){
   ...
});
```